# How do I transfer the contents of a player's enderchest to a different account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently wanted to replay a world, which I hosted as a server. I played with another account back then, and I transferred inventories using NBT-Explorer.

I also had an Ender chest with all my diamonds/valuables in it to protect it from the other players. The problem is: I don't know how to transfer its inventory so that it opens up with my new account.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4):

All ender chest items are stored in each player's unique playerdata files that can be found in "World\playerdata". Just like how you transferred the "Inventory" tag to the new player to copy their inventory, you can also transfer the "EnderItems" tag to the new player to copy their ender chest items. Just make sure the server is comepletely closed before you do this.

Comment: Leave a check on this answer if it helped you, it helps people know if the question is properly answered :)